# includes/navbar.php does not flow through to other pages

Tags: php, navigation, include

I have just downloaded a php starter site, and the index page showed

```
    require_once "Includes/simplecms-config.php"; 
    require_once  "Includes/connectDB.php";
    require "Includes/header.php";
```

All the blurb was here, and at the bottom

```
require "Includes/footer.php";
```

This was fine,and the format copied through to all pages, however the navbar was horizontal and included with the header. I want a vertical navbar and so created one and added

```
     require "Includes/navbar.php";
```

This worked, or so I thought until I navigated through to the other pages and the navbar doesn't show, so then I formatted the index page to include a navholder, and put 
        require "Includes/navbar.php"; inside that. Again it worked on the index page but not on any further ones. I'm a bit stuck now as the page I called "News" shows on the navbar, but in the header in IE shows as "localhost:19056/page.php?pageid=4" which I can't find in my file list.
Basically I can work out how to style the navbar and get it onto "Index.php" but not onto any other page.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you add require "Includes/navbar.php"; to all your other pages? Ideally you should add the contents of navbar.php to your header.php.

Comment: I did make the vertical navbar attached to the header.php, but then everything dropped below, not alongside

Comment: I finished up getting it to include by adding it to "page.php" and that worked, so this problem is solved, and I managed to solve the formatting problem too.